# Flutter cloud_functions Invalid argument: Instance of 'GeoPoint'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions

Hi I've been getting this error when trying to run a callable firebase function in flutter. I do not know the root of the cause any help will be much appreciated.

```
final HttpsCallable callable = CloudFunctions.instance.getHttpsCallable(
    functionName: 'firebaseFunction',
);

dynamic resp = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{
    "geoPoint" : geoPoint, //This is a variable with firestore class type GeoPoint
});
```

returns the error

> Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'GeoPoint'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Peter Haddad for bringing the root cause of the error alight.

> Only null, String, num, List or Map types can be used

A way round this I used was this. In flutter

```
dynamic resp = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{
  ///I split geopoint into its latitude and longitude
  "lat" : geoPoint.latitude,
  "long" : geoPoint.longitude,

  ///I split timestamp into its seconds and nanoseconds
  "seconds" : timestamp.seconds,
  "nanoseconds" : timestamp.nanoseconds,
});
```

I split geopoint into its latitude and longitude. This would also work for timestamps by splitting them into seconds and nanoseconds. Then in firebase functions I collected the data and rebuilt the classes uses admin.firestore.XXX()

```
const lat = data["lat"];
const long = data["long"];
const geoPoint = new admin.firestore.GeoPoint(lat, long);

const seconds = data["seconds"];
const nanoseconds = data["nanoseconds"];
const timeStamp = new admin.firestore.Timestamp(seconds, nanoseconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you cannot pass as instance of `geoPoint` as a value to the method `call` since it is not supported. According to the docs, the following are supported:

```
/// Executes this Callable HTTPS trigger asynchronously.
  ///
  /// The data passed into the trigger can be any of the following types:
  ///
  /// `null`
  /// `String`
  /// `num`
  /// [List], where the contained objects are also one of these types.
  /// [Map], where the values are also one of these types.
  ///
  /// The request to the Cloud Functions backend made by this method
  /// automatically includes a Firebase Instance ID token to identify the app
  /// instance. If a user is logged in with Firebase Auth, an auth ID token for
  /// the user is also automatically included
```

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_functions/lib/src/https_callable.dart

Example:

```
dynamic resp = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{
    'name': 'peter',
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that’s very helpful however how am able to pass such data e.g time stamp, geo point into the data. Should I pass nums into the function the make the function convert them into such classes

Comment: @GILO the call method in flutter, it invokes the `call` method in android https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/functions/HttpsCallableReference#public-taskhttpscallableresult-call-object-data you can see in the url what it takes as parameter